# Вопрос по событиям Python

Tags: python, события, websocket, декоратор

Допустим, у менять есть websocket. Как я могу в отдельном файле(скрипте) каждый раз когда получу от сокета сообщение - передать сообщение сокета для фуекции в скрипте, и выполнить ее?

Например, я видел как в discord.py, это было реализовано с использованием декоратов, но ничего не понял ибо нужен простой пример.

Comment: Файлу ничего передать нельзя. Передать можно функции или классу. Самое простое - импортируйте что нибудь из своего файла туда где идет обработка данных из сокета и вызывайте свою функцию, когда пришло что то ей предназначенное